# Creating a formula field in the opportunity with two IF statements

Tags: formula-field

I have been having troubles creating two if statements within a formula field.

I want one statement to calculate amount - expected renewal amount to give us the total upsell amount. But in the event where amount = expected renewal amount i want it to be a zero reflecting that there was no upsell. This is the criteria I am working with:

```
(Amount - Expected_Renewal_Amount__c)
(Amount = Expected_Renewal_Amount__c = 0,)
```

Comment: `x - x` equals 0, so I don't see why you need a second condition. Are you concerned that Amount may be less than Expected Renewal Amount, thus negative?

Comment: Yes because we would also like this to reflect potential downsells too,

Comment: In the same field or a different field? What's wrong with just `Amount - Expected_Renewal_Amount__c`?

Comment: That part of the formula works fine alone, its the second part that is messing up the formula where if "amount EQUALS expected renewal amount"  i want it to fill in the the field with zero showing that there was no upell or downsell.

Comment: Again, back to the original comment:  `x - x` is 0, indicating no upsell or downsell. So, I think it's all you need?

Comment: So effectively I would like to trigger the formula (Amount - Expected_Renewal_Amount__c) only if the expected renewal field is not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original formula (`Amount - Expected_Renewal_Amount__c`) is correct. Edit your formula and choose the "Treat blank fields as blank" option, which will cause the field to only show a value if both Amount and Expected Renewal Amount is populated.

If you still want it to show 0, as opposed to a blank value, you still need to set "Treat blank fields as blank", in which case the formula becomes:

```
IF(OR(ISBLANK(Amount), ISBLANK(Expected_Renewal_Amount__c)),
  0, Amount - Expected_Renewal_Amount__c)
```

Comment: @SebastianKessel Nope, the UI actually doesn't use the word null at all. The options are `Treat blank fields as zeroes` and `Treat blank fields as blanks`. I actually had the wrong verbiage, but not in the way you thought.